# How to validate a date without day with sfForm?

Tags: validation, forms, date, symfony1

I'm creating a payment form with symfony 1.4 , and my form has a date widget defined like this, so that the user can select the expiration date of his credit card:

```
new sfWidgetFormDate(array(
  'format' => '%month%/%year%',
  'years'  => array_combine(range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 5), range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 5))
```

Notice the absence of %day% in the format like in most payment forms.

Now my problem is that sfValidatorDate requires the 'day' field not to be empty. To work around this, I created a custom validator using a callback, which works well:

```
public function validateExpirationDate($validator, $value)
{
  $value['day'] = '15';
  $dateValidator = new sfValidatorDate(array(
    'date_format' => '#(?P<day>\d{2})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<year>\d{2})#',
    'required'    => false,
    'min'         => strtotime('first day of this month')));
  $dateValidator->clean($value);
  return $value;
}
```

I feel there might be a simpler way to achieve this. What do you think? Have you already solved this problem in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you store the date? If you just store month and year as integers or strings, then you can just make 2 choice widgets. But if you store it as datetime (timestamp), then you need a valid date anyway. This means that you need to automatically assign values to 'day' (usually first or last day of the month).

```
class YourForm extends BaseYourForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['date'] = new sfWidgetFormDate(array(
      'format' => '%month%/%year%'
    ));
    $this->validatorSchema['date'] = new myValidatorDate(array(
      'day_default' => 1
    ));
  }
} 

class myValidatorDate extends sfValidatorDate
{
  protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
  {
    $this->addOption('day_default', 1);
    parent::configure($options, $messages);
  }

  protected function doClean($value)
  {
    if (!isset($value['day']))
    {
      $value['day'] = $this->getOption('day_default');
    }
    return parent::doClean($value);
  }
}
```

Comment: For the moment, I don't store it, but I will store it as a future, most likely as a string since the web service I'm sending it to only needs a string. Or maybe as a timestamp if I want to use this to alert my user when his credit card expires. Anyway, the code in my (and your) configure method creates two select boxes. My point is I want to have a valid date in the current month or later. This is what both our codes do, but your seems more configurable, so +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a custom validation class: you can simply override the tainted values passed to your bind() method:

```
  <?php
  // in your form class
  public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null)
  {
    $taintedValues['date']['day'] = 1;

    return parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used simplest way, for validate credit card expiration day:

```
$post_data = $request->getParameter('my_form');
$post_data['card_exp']['day'] = 1; //sets the first day of the month
$this->form->bind($post_data);
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this first in the form class

```
    $year = range(date('Y'), date('Y') - 50);

    $this->widgetSchema['date'] = new sfWidgetFormDate(array(
      'format' => '%year%',
      'years' => array_combine($year, $year),
      'can_be_empty' => false
    ));
```

Next...

```
    public function bind(array $taintedValues = null){
      $taintedValues['date']['day'] = '01';
      $taintedValues['date']['month'] = '01';

      parent::bind($taintedValues);
    }
```

The field in the database is date type DATE.

Comment: +1, this is def the best solution imo. Keep the logic at the form layer, and no need for custom validation. Yet you still ensure consistent validation and storage.